# Bootstrap slider value from 250000 to 250.000

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i make fix value from xxxxxx to xxx.xxx and x.xxx.xxx dotting it?

```js
$('#ex1').slider({
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Aktualny wybór: ' + value;
    }
});

$("#ex1").slider();
$("#ex1").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex1SliderVal").val(slideEvt.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://motoopinia.pl/app/templates/default/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://motoopinia.pl/app/templates/default/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<input id="ex1SliderVal" size="6" type="text" name="przebieg" class="form-text" value="250000" readonly="readonly" placeholder="125000"></div><div style="width: 75%;display: inline-block;margin-left: 5%;">
<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" style="width:100%;" data-slider-min="5000" data-slider-max="1000000" data-slider-step="5000" data-slider-value="125000"/></div>
```

Comment: What does mean 250000

Comment: can you clear your question more specifically?

Comment: decinal point when i choose value 15000 i want to show it like that 15.000 now its clear?